# NoClassDefFoundError: org/directwebremoting/extend/ConvertUtil

Tags: java, tomcat, dwr

After moving a Tomcat app from one server to the other, we get this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dwr-invoker threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/directwebremoting/extend/ConvertUtil
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.CallBatch.parseParameters(CallBatch.java:135)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.CallBatch.<init>(CallBatch.java:47)
        at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:72)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

We have the dwr.jar in the WEB-INF/lib dir (and I opened it and checked, the org/directwebremoting/extend/ConvertUtil is there)

```
/srv/tomcat6/webapps/APPNAME/WEB-INF/lib/dwr.jar
```

**UPDATE** this is how DWR dependency is defined in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
        <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
        <version>3.rc1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/dwr.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Open the dwr.jar and check if org/directwebremoting/extend/ConvertUtil is there.

Comment: I opened the dwr.jar and the org/directwebremoting/extend/ConvertUtil is there.

Comment: Maybe file permissions? It would require some weird setup to get a classpath error...

Comment: Try to build it with compile scope in order to have the right pom within app.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple, file permissions look OK.

Comment: @user987339, this app has been in production for years, the problem occurs only after deployment to a new server.

Comment: I noticed that, but your system path is very strange, so maybe this is not configured right on your new server. On the other hand can you try to build this app as I suggested?